# How to split train test data when having a date column?

Tags: python, time-series, lightgbm, train-test-split

I found some other question like my own, sorry for asking a repeated one, but honestly couldn’t understand yet.

I have a very large dataset that a sample of that could be like below.

```
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'date': ['2022-08-01', '2022-08-03', '2022-08-02','2022-08-07', '2022-08-08', '2022-08-06', '2022-08-05', '2022-08-04'],
        'device': ['mobile', 'mobile', 'TV', 'YouTube','PC', 'YouTube', 'PC', 'PC'],
       'imp': [0, 120, 400, 100,40, 50, 20, 110],
       'AM/PM': ['AM', 'PM', 'AM', 'AM','PM', 'AM', 'PM', 'PM'],
       'ID': [44995, 44996, 44997, 54828, 98726, 43261, 56436, 98765]}


# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  
# Print the output.
df

      date      device  imp AM/PM   ID
0   2022-08-01  mobile  0   AM  44995
1   2022-08-03  mobile  120 PM  44996
2   2022-08-02  TV      400 AM  44997
3   2022-08-07  YouTube 100 AM  54828
4   2022-08-08  PC      40  PM  98726
5   2022-08-06  YouTube 50  AM  43261
6   2022-08-05  PC      20  PM  56436
7   2022-08-04  PC      110 PM  98765
```

I should use lightgbm to estimate imp.
How can I split my data in a way that do not use future data in my train set.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df=df.sort_values(by='date’)

X = df.drop(columns = ['imp']).copy()
y = df['imp’]

(this line mixes all the dates)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.8, random_state=42)
```

Preferably I want to use two month of the data to train the model and test on its next one week.

```
1st train: 2021-01-01 to 2021-03-01
1st test:  2021-03-02 to 2021-03-08
2nd train: 2021-03-02 to 2021-05-01
2nd test:  2021-05-02 to 2021-05-08 so on so forth
```

if the above is not possible, just split train-test to 8:2

The dataset is for one year and half period.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand. Do you want to create two DataFrames ? One with the last month and one with the next week ?

Comment: @rochard4u sorry for being so vague, beginner in ML. I added some extra rows to my question.

Comment: I think that https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html will help you.

Comment: A rather crude method to slice your data would be : import the dateutil module => apply `dateutil.parser.parse` to the `date` column => generate a mask using comparison operators `mask = df["date"].apply(lambda date: start <= date <= end)` => use the mask to filter df `slice = df[mask]`

Comment: @rochard4u I had tested the timeseriessplit, however couldn’t figure out what parameters gave me what I need. Thank you for the last method.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your request, you have very clear clue how to prepare your training dataset and testing dataset right

Training Data: 2 Months Period

Testing Data: 1 Week after 2 Month Period

Which means you don't need the following code to prepare your training and testing data, the reason why we using the code is because we need to use a random way to prepare our dataset., you have your logic and thought then you can prepare your data base Pandas and You can use Numpy to create your Dependent and Independent variable

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values
:
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.8, random_state=42)
```

I you still have question regarding how to use pandas to create your training and testing data from your master table please let us know.

Thanks
Leon

Comment: Thank you. What if I simply want to split the whole dataset to 8:2.How should I handle the time column? to prevent having the future data on my train set.

Comment: Hi Sam, Actually if you want to use this function to split you can't set the condition from this Split function, My suggestion, you set the time condition first before using the Split function.